# FLVPlayback Skin: Overlay controls, don't render them below video

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flvplayback

I am using a built-in skin to render the controls for a FLVPlayback component. However, while other skins render themselves over the video, this one renders them below the video. I've searched for hours and cannot find the option / tweak to make it behave like an overlay. Can someone help me?

My current skin is "MinimalFlatCustomColorPlayBackSeekCounterVolMuteFull.swf".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the skin there is a "Video Placeholder" layer, which is near the controls. It might be disabled, so you need to enable the layer in the timeline first. After that, you can position the placeholder so that it overlaps the controls.